# R quarto include file not linking to ggplot2 images

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I have an RStudio quarto project which has an index page that links multiple chapters. These chapters are in their own folder `chapters` and include executed R code. The R code executes fine, but when it is used to create graphs in ggplot2 the graph image can't be found due to the project structure:

###### index.qmd

```
# Introduction to quantitative methods

{{< include chapters/_01-Intro_to_quant_methods.qmd >}}
```

###### chapters/_01-Intro_to_quant_methods.qmd

````
```{r}
#| warning: false
#| message: false
# This example shows how R can pull data directly from the internet
# tidy it and start making graphs. All within 9 lines of code
library(tidyverse)

education <- read_csv(
  "https://barrolee.github.io/BarroLeeDataSet/BLData/BL_v3_MF.csv")

education %>%
  filter(agefrom == 15, ageto == 24,
         country %in% c("Germany","France","Italy","United Kingdom")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=yr_sch, colour=country)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```
````

The index.html page is output without the image. The issue being it is looking for the image in the wrong location, up the chapters folder tree:

```
<img src="chapters/index_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-1-1.png" class="img-fluid" width="672">
```

When it actually lives at:

```
index_files\figure-html\unnamed-chunk-1-1.png
```

[image]

How can I make included chunks output their images to the correct location?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.   For me this is working exactly as expected.  The file is being created in `index_files\figure-html\unnamed-chunk-1-1.png` and it is loaded successfully from there.

Comment: That is good news, maybe it's something with my YAML. Let me try and work on a simpler reproducible example